# Issue with if else continue statement within foreach loop

Tags: powershell

I have the following for loop.My question is, if I use continue statement for the first if statement then the second if statement (saveto) not working. From what I see , I assuming there is a logic error. 
it would workflow like below :

-All parameter is null and SaveTo parameter is not null , attachment filter will execute and second if statement will execute.

-All parameter is not null and SaveTo parameter is not null , attachment filter won't execute and second if statement will execute.

```
foreach ($attachment in $attachments.value) {
    # weed out unwanted attachments
    # Use the All siwtch to include them
    If (!$All) {
        If ($attachment.Size -lt 100000 -and $attachment.contentType -like '*image*') {
            #images from less then 100kb
            continue
        } ElseIf ($attachment.contentType -eq 'application/octet-stream' ) {
            #bin files
            continue
            }
    }

    If ($SaveTo) {
        $timestamp = $attachment.DateTimeLastModified.Replace(':','')
        $path = "$SaveTo\$timestamp`_$($attachment.name)"
        #$path = "C:\path\" + $attachment.Name

        $Content = [System.Convert]::FromBase64String($attachment.ContentBytes)
        Set-Content -Path $path -Value $Content -Encoding Byte  
    }

}
```

Comment: why don't you filter using exactly your text? `if (!$All -and !$SaveTo)` and `if ($All -and $SaveTo)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are specifically instructing your code to skip the `$saveto` part if `$all` is not `$null` by using the `Continue` statement.

> ## Continue
>
> Return to top of a program loop, skip just this iteration of the loop.
>
> In a For, ForEach or While loop you can add a continue statement to
>   jump to the top of the innermost loop.
>
> ## Example
>
> Count to 10 but miss out the number 5:
>
> ```
> $i =0
>  while ($i -lt 10)
>      {
>        $i +=1 
>        if ($i -eq 5) {continue}
>        Write-Host $i
>      }
> ```
>
> Source:[SS64 - Continue statement](https://ss64.com/ps/continue.html)

The only scenario where `Continue` can be used to not exit a loop is in a `Switch` statement. In this specific scenario, the `Continue` statement will indicate that you would like to skip remaining condition block and evaluate the next condition in the current `Switch`.

Reference

[SS64 - Switch statement](https://ss64.com/ps/switch.html)

Answer (score 0):

That is what the continue statement is for: jump back to the start of the foreach loop and start with the next $attachment. Seel also [here](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2014/05/09/powershell-looping-the-continue-statement/)